# xpath request to select element that have commun attribute

Tags: xml, database, xpath

I'm facing a difficult request that i can't resolve.

So for example this is our xml database:

```
<root>
    <A>
       <B attr="b">
       ... 
       </B>

       <C attr="c">
       ...
       </C>
    </A>
    <A>
       <B attr="b">
       ... 
       </B>
       <C attr="c">
       ...
       </C>
    </A>
    <A>
       <B attr="notb">
       ... 
       </B>
       <C attr="notc">
       ...
       </C>
    </A>
</root>
```

**The Question is** : what are the A element child of the root that have in commun the attribute attr in their childs B and C.

In our example the first element A and the second elemnt A should be in the awnser , because their attribute attr are equal in B and C.the last element A will be not in the anwser.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//A[B/@attr=following-sibling::A/B/@attr and C/@attr=following-sibling::A/C/@attr]
```

The trick is to use the `following-sibling` axis, so you can look for the next elements, not the previous ones.

More on XPath axes can be found [in here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

As pointed out by Andersson in the comments, it should be:

```
//A[
    (
        B/@attr=following-sibling::A/B/@attr and 
        C/@attr=following-sibling::A/C/@attr
    )
    or 
    (
        B/@attr=preceding-sibling::A/B/@attr and 
        C/@attr=preceding-sibling::A/C/@attr
    )]
```

Comment: +1, but this won't return required output as it seem that OP wants *all* `A` nodes with common attributes (*"...first element A and the second element A should be in the awnser"*). Might be updated as `//A[(B/@attr=following-sibling::A/B/@attr and C/@attr=following-sibling::A/C/@attr) or (B/@attr=preceding-sibling::A/B/@attr and C/@attr=preceding-sibling::A/C/@attr)]`

Comment: You're right, @Andersson, my bad! Add that as an answer and I'll delete this one

Comment: @RubensFarias i tought that it was the correct awnser but today i reviewd your awnser and it seems not the perfect solution.from you query we can get false A (some A1 that have the same attrB with A2 and the same attrC in another A3).

Comment: @Andersson but my question was about two A that have the same attb and the same attc